# Spring redirect to another page on button click

Tags: html, spring, redirect

I'm new to the Spring framework. At the moment I've got two `HTML` pages and when a button is clicked on the first one I want to redirect to the second page.

At the moment I'm doing this in a really hacky way.

The first page is just a log in page and depending on the user logged I'm redirection to a specific page. On the login page I've got two hidden `<a>` like these

```
<a href="admin" class="button" id="btnAdmin" style="opacity: 0;"> Login as tutor </a>
<a href="student" class="button" id="btnStudent" style="opacity: 0;"> Login as student</a>
```

Then using JavaScript I'm triggering this `<a>` to be clicked when the Login button is clicked. That way I'm successfully redirecting to the `admin.html` or `student.html` pages. The problem is that once I'm redirected to these pages the page is not rendered correctly (the js is not loaded correctly) so I need to refresh the page to see the proper content of the page. I assume that the reason for is because I'm redirecting in such a hacky way. So my question is - having a button like this (ignore the `JQuery Mobile`)

```
<input type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btnLogin" value="Sigh in" data-theme="b"/>
```

how to redirect properly in the Spring framework?

PS I'm coming from ASP.NET background so I was thinking of some sort of button click event handler in the back end, and then doing something like `Response.Redirect("newpage");`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but basically handling links and buttons is pure client-side task and has nothing to do with any server-side implementations, no matter if it's Java+Spring, or ASP.NET.

But if you really want to know how to redirect in Spring, the easiest way is to just return `redirect:path` from your action:

```java
@Controller
class MyController
{
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public String myAction()
    {
        /* your logic here */
        return 'redirect:student';
    }
}
```